# Problema com "ver mais"(botão)!

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, foreach

Estou com um pequeno projeto que é de otimizar o "ver mais" em um site ou aplicação e me deparei com um problema.

```
<div class="conteudo">
  <h2>
    <span>teste</span>
  </h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
. Donec tincidunt quis nibh eget feugiat. 
  </p>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="conteudo">
  <h2>
    <span>teste2</span>
  </h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
. Donec tincidunt quis nibh eget feugiat. 
  </p>
  <hr />
</div>

<div class="conteudo">
  <h2>
    <span>teste3</span>
  </h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
. Donec tincidunt quis nibh eget feugiat. 
  </p>
  <hr />
</div>
```

A ideia é que cada vez que se clique no que está escrito no "span", eu consiga visualizar o texto e ao clicar novamente nele, eu consiga esconder o texto.

Fazer uma função pra isso é bem fácil na verdade, alterando o valor de T, você consegue fazer os botoes funcionarem.

```
t = 0;
var span = document.querySelectorAll(".conteudo span")[t];

span1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var cont = document.querySelectorAll(".conteudo p")[t];

  if (cont.classList.contains("mostrar")) {
    cont.classList.remove("mostrar");
  } else {
    cont1.classList.add("mostrar");
  }
});
```

Com isso, você resolve o problema, porém, a partir daqui que a coisa fica "complicada". Para se "resolver" esse problema, você teria que copiar o código em JS várias vezes e alterar o valor de T.
Eu tava tentando fazer isso de uma forma que eu não precise duplicar o código e alterar o valor dele.

Então, recorro aos senhores, colegas programadores pra me ajudar nessa maravilhosa empreitada infernal.

Peço perdão de forma antecipada, eu sou iniciante na programação e posto no fórum pela primeira vez.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria usar o `target` do click para identificar o elemento clickado e depois adicionar/remover (usando o `classList.toggle`) a classe `mostrar`.

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'h2' && e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('conteudo')) {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('mostrar');
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

p.mostrar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
  <h2>Teste 1</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt quis nibh eget feugiat.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo">
  <h2>Teste 2</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt quis nibh eget feugiat.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="conteudo">
  <h2>Teste 3</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt quis nibh eget feugiat.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sem duvidas, porém eu ainda teria o problema de que teriam outras classes com o mesmo problema de ao clicar na mesma, o conteúdo não aparecer, apenas na primeira selecionada.

Comment: Confesso que tenho bastante dificuldade em entender o que pretende. Já várias vezes, quer  a sua pergunta, quer o comentário, e continua sem ser claro aquilo que pretende fazer. Consegue especificar um pouco mais?

Comment: Vou editar a postagem de forma que fique mais fácil a compreensão.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. É isto que pretende?

Comment: Quase isso, mas a tua resposta me deu um bum do que precisava ser feito.

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = document.querySelectorAll(".conteudo");
```

Consegui resolver o problema, acabei tendo que usar for each.

```
span.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const phr = this.querySelector("p");
    if (phr.classList.contains("mostrar")) {
      phr.classList.remove("mostrar");
    } else {
      phr.classList.add("mostrar");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Desta forma a classe é adicionada/removida sempre que clique em qualquer zona de uma div conteúdo, ou seja, quando o parágrafo está visível e for clicado, também vai esconder. A sua pergunta dá a entender que o parágrafo deve ser mostrado/escondido apenas quando clica no h2.
Só mais uma sugestão ... pode facilmente substituir o if/else utilizando o classList.toggle, como no código que escrevi anteriormente.